# Printing Multiple Pages in a Winform application

Tags: c#, printdocument

I am attempting to print something using a C# Winforms application. I can't seem to understand how multiple pages works. Let's say I have the following code in my constructor:

```
private string _stringToPrint;
_stringToPrint = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 120; i++)
{
    _stringToPrint = _stringToPrint + "Line " + i.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Then I have this code on my button click event:

```
private void MnuFilePrintClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrintPage += pd_PrintPage;

    var z = new PrintPreviewDialog { Document = pd };

    z.ShowDialog(this);
}

void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    var font = new Font("Arial", 10f, FontStyle.Regular);

    g.DrawString(_stringToPrint, font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(10f, 10f));
}
```

Right now, when I run this code, it is giving me one page and after like 70 lines, it just runs off the paper. How would I print this string so that it prints enough for one page, then runs over to the second page, etc..?

Comment: This question must have been asked thousands of times before.  Sure, it doesn't fit.  That's something you discover from the Graphics.MeasureString() overloads that returns *charactersFitted*.  So that you can set e.HasMorePages to true and print the rest on the next page.  And of course you'll need BeginPrint to reset the index.

Comment: @HansPassant - I really did Google this before asking it. It seems like it would have been a lot easier if Microsoft had a `Page` property attached to the `PrintPageEventArgs` that would be set to whatever page is currently being rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a counter and set the amount of lines you want per page like so:

```
private string[] _stringToPrint = new string[100]; // 100 is the amount of lines
private int counter = 0;
private int amtleft = _stringToPrint.Length;
private int amtperpage = 40; // The amount of lines per page
for (int i = 0; i < 120; i++)
{
    _stringToPrint[i] ="Line " + i.ToString();
}
```

Then in `pd_PrintPage`:

```
void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    int currentamt = (amtleft > 40)?40:amtleft;
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    var font = new Font("Arial", 10f, FontStyle.Regular);
    for(int x = counter; x < (currentamt+counter); x++)
    {
        g.DrawString(_stringToPrint[x], font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(10f, (float)x*10));
        // x*10 is just so the lines are printed downwards and not on top of each other
        // For example Line 2 would be printed below Line 1 etc
    }
    counter+=currentamt;
    amtleft-=currentamt;
    if(amtleft<0)
        e.HasMorePages = true;
    else
        e.HasMorePages = false;
    // If e.HasMorePages is set to true and the 'PrintPage' has finished, it will print another page, else it wont
}
```

I have had bad experiences with `e.HasMorePages` so this may not work.

Let me know if this works and I hope it helps!

Comment: This code works Matthew, but is this the simplest way to do this? Seems like a lot of math just to print one long string

Comment: There isn't really a way to do it better, most of the math is for calculating how many to print on the current page, how many more is to go and the current line. To me it is the simplest way to do it but if you don't understand it fully I can help you in SO chat.